# how to generate textfield based on the data in database using yii

Tags: yii

i'm trying to generate a form, based on the data retrieved in the database and one of the data will be represented by a textfield. i want to make that textfield an array in order to hold the values with only one variable because after user modifying the form i will save the information in the database per row. this is my code....

```
<?php foreach($milestone_list as $milestone_list): 
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        echo $milestone_list->Id;
                    echo '</td>';

                    echo '<td>';
                        echo $milestone_list->Milestone;
                    echo '</td>';

                    echo '<td>';
                        echo $milestone_list->Responsibility;
                    echo '</td>';

                    echo '<td>';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                            echo $form->labelEx($model,'Duration_Value');
                            echo $form->textField($model,'Duration_Value'). 'Day/s';
                            echo $form->error($model,'Duration_Value');
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</td>';


                    echo '</tr>';
            endforeach; ?>
```

can anyone do this??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`echo $form->textField($model,'Duration_Value')` is done in circle, but `Duration_Value` attribute is unique to any model of AR! => your code is wrong.

I'd recommend to put a simple textfield: `CHtml::textField('Duration_Value'. $i++)` inside a circle, iterating over `$i` variable. It's not model related, but on server side you iterate over `$_POST['Duration_Value1']`,  `$_POST['Duration_Value2']` ... to fetch and save data in db (or AR).

Comment: i want textfield to have the same name like Duration_Value. and in order to do that, the textfield should be an array like this: Duration_Value[0],Duration_Value[1],Duration_Value[2],Duration_Value[3]...... and so on.....

Comment: it's not possible to store array in an AR model attribute!!

Comment: ahhh thanks. maybe i use the traditional way. but thanks @igor